# Retrieving Base64 data from Oracle using C# into JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, oracle, base64

I've written an ASP.NET web service that takes requests, gathers data from an Oracle Database and sends back the information via JSON.  The data includes an image file (jpg) that needs to be returned in Base64.

All was going well until I tried to return the image.  My code is as follows:

Oracle Stored Procedure:  (paraphrased)

```
create or replace PROCEDURE check_data(
<in parameters here>,
outpixblob      OUT BLOB);

fileptr := utl_file.fopen('PIX_DIR', vFilename, 'rb', 32760);
utl_file.get_raw(fileptr, outpixblob);
```

This seems to work well, in that I've traced through it and am seeing predictable data returned (base64 string)

Now, to the C# code:

```
conn.Open();
            var cmd = new OracleCommand
            {
                Connection = conn,
                CommandText = "CHECK_DATA",
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            };
            //lots of parameter settings here, just showing the pertinent one
            //cmd.Parameters.Add("outpixblob", OracleDbType.Blob).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            var dr = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            var blob = (OracleBlob) cmd.Parameters["outpixblob"].Value;

            var buffer = new byte[blob.Length];
            blob.BeginChunkWrite();
            blob.Write(buffer, 0, (int)blob.Length);
            blob.EndChunkWrite();
            string photoString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);


            result = new VisitorCheckResult
            {
                ...
                Photo     =     photoString,

            };
```

I've obviously cut out non-essential code again, but I believe the idea of what I'm doing is there.

The result of photostring is not the values I saw when I debugged the Oracle sproc; instead, it is a long string of '\u0000' over and over again.

I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing, but being a n00b at this I'm not able to see what it is.

Help!

Comment: `photoString` is the image encoded to `UTF8`, not to base 64.

Comment: what encoding should I use instead?

Comment: Have you tried System.Convert.FromBase64String() or System.Convert.FromBase64CharArray() ?

Comment: I did, and the result I got was a long string of 'AAAAAAAAA' ad infinitum.

Comment: 1) You cannot encode arbitrary binary data using `UTF8.GetString()`.  bytes that are not valid Unicode UTF-8 characters will be replaced with a "fallback character", see [Choosing a Fallback Strategy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377.aspx).  2) Have you verified that `buffer` contains what you expect after calling `blob.EndChunkWrite()`?  3) Have you tried returning the `byte [] buffer` array directly?  Most JSON serializers are able to serialize byte arrays natively, e.g. [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm) serializes to base64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the answer.  Turns out I was using the write() method with the incorrect idea that it would write to the buffer.  The Write() method writes data TO the Oracle BLOB object.  I needed instead to use the Read() Method.

Once that happened, and after I converted the byte[] array to base64:

```
result.Photo = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
```

The result came out beautifully.

Thanks to all, and especially thanks to dbc, whose response helped me realize what was going on.